# QGIS connect to WCS using OAuth2

Tags: qgis, authentication, wcs

I'm trying to connect my QGIS to a WCS service using OAuth2 authentication (see *curl example* below to understand the authentication workflow).

***the problem***

The option "add WCS layer" seemed to be the obvious right choice, but the OAuth2 authentication makes it difficult. I would need to

1. get an access token
2. add this token to the http header along with the actual wcs request

Now. When I try to connect using "add wcs layer", I can choose to enter a username and password for basic auth, but I just cannot find any possibility to use the OAuth2 authentication protocol.

***curl example***

Using curl, the whole thing works as follows:

`curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST -d "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=<myTestScope>&client_id=<myClientId>&client_secret=<myClientSecret>" <https-urlToGenerateToken>`

I get as a repsonse my token in json format:

`{
  "token_type":"Bearer",
  "access_token": <myToken>,
  "expires_in":3600,
  "scope": <myTestScope>
}`

This, I can then use to call the service:

`curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer <myToken>" <wcsURL>/getCapabilities`

***the question***

Is there a standard way to use this OAuth2 authentication workflow in qgis when connecting to a service, and I just couldn't find it? If there is no standard way, can I somehow "hook in" and add custom headers?

---

*Edit - Tried GDAL driver:*

As suggested in the comments section, I tried to use the [GDAL driver](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_wcs.html). I didn't quite figure out how to use it from within QGIS (but I assume it's possible). Instead, I tried it from the command line (creating the respective xml-file and calling `gdalinfo file.xml`).

- Could connect to the test server (no authentication)
- Could connect to the server when using Basic Auth, by adding the `<UserPwd>` tag as documented in the GDAL Driver doc.
- The problem with OAuth2 is still not solved. Setting `<HttpAuth>` to `ANY` and stuff doesn't work. Also, this makes total sense, as I would really need to make 2 different calls (1. token, 2. wcs-request) to two different url's, but the GDAL Driver accepts only one ServiceURL.

Comment: Did you see if you could do it with the [GDAL WCS driver](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_wcs.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the input, nmtoken. :) I now tried, and greatly failed with this, too... See the edit above.

Comment: C'est la vie! `(but I assume it's possible)`, yes, once you have created the XML file you can `Load` it in QGIS, through the `Add layer(s) from a WCS Server`

Comment: Indeed, found that option, thanks. The original problem remains. My next steps would go towards Authentication plugins (see "Authentication Methods" here: https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/auth_system/auth_overview.html). Hopefully won't have to make the effort of writing one myself. At least for QGIS server, they seem to have some OAuth stuff. Will keep you posted.